# PARSE AN INTENT IN ANDROID

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-intent

I have this code at Main_Screen.class:

```
    add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent add_user = new Intent(Main_Screen.this, Add_Update_User.class);
            add_user.putExtra("called", "add");
            add_user.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(add_user);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

What I understood is that I'm sending to "Add_Update_User.class" the string "add" stored in "called" and the flags"

Now, I have this code at "Add_Update_User.class":

```
    String called_from = getIntent().getStringExtra("called");
    if (called_from.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) 
    {
        add_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        update_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } 
    else 
    {
        update_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        add_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        USER_ID = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ID"));
        Contact c = dbHandler.Get_Contact(USER_ID);

        add_name.setText(c.getName());
        add_mobile.setText(c.getPhoneNumber());
        add_email.setText(c.getEmail());
    }
```

What I understood in "Add_Update_User.class" I'm getting the values sent from "Main_Screen.class" in the Intent, storing the value "add" in the String "called_from" and then it compares "called from" with the string "add" and if the comparison is true the view goes visible and gone but if it's not true then  set the visibilities of the view AND HERE GOES MY QUESTION:

WHAT THE HELL DOES THIS PART OF THE CODE?

```
    USER_ID = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ID"));
```

Comment: Your caps lock key gets stuck occasionally?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you are sending "add" value from main_screen to add_update_user via the Intent.

The line that you are pointing is the same except that your are extracting a user id which is a String. However your variable USER_ID is probably an "int" type.

Therefore you should have somewhere in your main_screen something like

```
add_user.putExtra("USERID", "the id of the user you want to put");
```

and you retrieve it with

```
 getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ID")
```

then you parse the string into an integer to match the type of user_id with Integer.parseInt(...)

The real question therefore you need to ask yourself is why you do not have the function add_user.putExtra("USER_ID",...) if you do not need it then you can remove the line you are concerned with.

Comment: I have that part that you say, let me edit the question. But Now i know what the hell does that part of the code. Thanks :D